# Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket':

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to run this code:

```
function smConnect() {
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1805/');
  delete ws.URL;

  ws.onopen = function(response) {};
  ws.onmessage = function(response) {};
  ws.onclose = function(response) {};
  ws.onerror = function(error) {};
}

smConnect();
ws.send('message', 'hi');
```

But it returns me this error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.

What could be the problem?

Comment: run the _send_ from inside the _onopen_ handler. or, define your own send() on smConnect, and buffer until `ws.readyState==1`

Comment: @dandavis I need to run out, have some means?

Comment: @dandavis I'm kind of layman, is to show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this, it adds some logging, the sending of the info you can handle outside of your constructor, and you would also have abstracted away the SocketWrapper in its own namespace (ok, yes, it's in window now :))

You can check the dev tools (F12 in most browsers) to see whats happening in the logs/error, eg: here it throws an error, as there is no socket available :)

And you are not required to give a value for all events, just the ones you need (your case onopen + maybe onmessage?)

(inside the defined callbacks, this would point towards the socket, not the SocketWrapper, the SocketWrapper also doesn't offer the ws variable, it's kind of private, but it should do i guess)

There is a send method on the SocketWrapper, that throws an error, when you send to a closed stream, but in case it wasn't opened yet, it will queue the messages till it gets opened and then empty the queue to the websocket (so in a sence, you are not required to set the onopen callback, just adding it using the send method should be fine ;)

```js
(function(nameSpace) {
  function createMethod(method, options, stateCallback) {
    var that = this;
    this[method] = function() {
      if (stateCallback && stateCallback.apply) {
        stateCallback(method);
      }
      console.info(method);
      if (options[method] && options[method].apply) {
        options[method].apply(that, arguments);
      }
    };
  }

  function SocketWrapper(options) {
    var ws,
      events = ['onopen', 'onmessage', 'onclose', 'onerror'],
      i, len, prop = {
        opened: false,
        closed: false,
        error: false
      },
      method;

    if (typeof options === 'undefined' || !options) {
      throw 'ArgumentException: please add default constructor options';
    }
    
    this.queue = [];
    
    this.onEventTrigger = function(eventName) {
      var i, len;
      if (eventName === 'onopen') {
        prop.opened = true;
        prop.closed = false;
        // openend send queue
        if (this.queue.length > 0) {
          for (i = this.queue.length; --i >= 0;) {
            this.send.apply(this, this.queue[0]);
            this.queue.splice(0, 1);
          }
        }
      }
      if (eventName === 'onerror') {
        prop.error = true;
      }
      if (eventName === 'onclosed') {
        prop.opened = false;
        prop.closed = true;
      }
    };

    this.init = function() {
      var cb = this.onEventTrigger.bind(this);
      ws = new WebSocket(options.url);

      for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        method = events[i];
        createMethod.apply(ws, [method, options, cb]);
      }
    };

    this.send = function() {
      if (prop.closed) {
        throw 'InvalidOperation: Cannot send messages to a closed Websocket!';
      }
      if (!prop.opened) {
        this.queue.push(arguments);
      } else {
        ws.send.apply(ws, arguments);
      }
    };
    
    this.init();
    return this;
  }

  window.SocketWrapper = SocketWrapper;
}(window));

var socket = new window.SocketWrapper({
  url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:1805',
  onopen: function() {
    this.send('message', 'hi');
  },
  onmessage: function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  },
  onclose: function() {
    socket = null;
  },
  onerror: function() {
    console.log('error occured, oh no!');
    console.error(arguments);
  }
});
socket.send('i am message send to soon, but since i check the state of the ws object, i will be queued and send when appropriate');
```